# Filter IEnumerable

Tags: c#, filtering

I have 3 classes with the following properties:

OfferList class:

```
Guid Id
IEnumerable<Offer> Offers
```

Offer class:

```
Guid Id
Product Product
bool IsSealed
```

Product class:

```
Guid Id
```

An OfferList contains multiple Offers and an Offer has exact 1 Product.

How can I filter the OfferList to contain only Offers which are not sealed?

```
OfferList offerList = this.GetOfferList(id).Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed));
```

This returns an IEnumerable of type Offer instead of filtering the OfferList.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interesting - it is a little confusing what you're asking here.

I *think* you're asking how to have `Offers` filtered in-place.  If so:

`IEnumerable<T>` is immutable (you have to cast to a concrete `List<T>` or similar to get mutability), and `Offers` is an `IEnumerable<T>` - so you can't expect `Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed));` to *change* the `Offers` property - it returns an enumerable that filters the source as you enumerate it.

Instead you'd do

```
var offerList = this.GetOfferList(id)
offerList.Offers = offerList.Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed));
```

Note, however, that this hides the original `Offers` reference for any other code sharing that `OfferList` instance.  It also doesn't actually do any filtering until you start enumerating, either.  But that's often preferable.  If you want it done there and then - use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` at the end of the `Where` to force the enumeration to be done.

A better approach would be to have a property or method on the `OfferList` class that returns a new enumerable on-demand:

```
public IEnumerable<Offer> UnsealedOffers {
  get {
    return Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed);
  }
}
```

That way you're not destroying the master enumerable.

Note that this code is susceptible to `Offers` being null (a `NullReferenceException`) *and* that it's not great to return null enumerables (return empty ones instead) - so if there is a chance that `Offers` can be null - then either stop that from happening; or use:

```
return (Offers ?? Enumerable.Empty<Offer>()).Where(o => !o.IsSealed);
```

Comment: the second approach solves my problem in a quite brilliant way. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to update your original `OfferList` instance, you could just assign the filtered sequence to its `Offers` field:

```
OfferList offerList = this.GetOfferList(id);
offerList.Offers = offerList.Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a new list of un-sealed offers?

```
List<Offer> offers = this.GetOfferList(id).Offers
                         .Where(o => !o.IsSealed)
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Offers` of your `OfferList` class. You can't directly cast to the `OfferList` because it isn't a `List` or doesn't implement `IEnumerable`.

`OfferList list = new OfferList() { Offers = this.GetOfferList(id).Offers.Where(o => !o.IsSealed)) };`